# Point one object to face a distant object

Tags: three.js

I have two objects, let's call them nearObject and farObject.  Once nearObject gets within a certain distance from farObject, I want farObject to rotate to face nearObject.  This should happen instantly, it does not need to slowly rotate over time.

1)  The distance is arbitrary, so I am using the following to get distance information.
nearObject.position.distanceToSquared(farObject.position);

2)  Now I want farObject to rotate perpendicular to the vector between the two objects.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
farObject.lookAt( nearObject.position );
```

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it to.  Far object is a mesh.  When I create it, I do the following to get it aligned vertically.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it to.  Far object is a mesh.  When I create it, I do the following to get it aligned vertically so that it can be seen.

mesh.rotation = new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI/2, 0, 0);

Then when I do what you suggested above, the mesh gets aligned so that it is facing up, which can't be seen from the camera.  Then when I set the rotation again, it seems to cancel what lookAt() did.  How do I get it to just rotate towards nearObject on the xz plane along the y axis?

Comment: For the benefit of others, why not accept this as the answer to your original question (since it is), and then post another more specific question in a new post? Add a live example if you can, so we can understand exactly what your additional requirements are.